# One liner for if statement in shell script

Tags: shell

I have specified a variable like this in shell script,

```
organisation="${organisation:-'$1/'}"
```

I have passed $1 as "repo" while executing this script,
then organisation variable is echoed as "repo/". without passing $1 it's "/", Which i don't want.

My Question is i want this variable to print null if $1 is not passed or print "repo/" if $1 is passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will assign `organization` to `$1/` if `$1` was passed to the script and set it to empty otherwise:

```
[ "$1" ] && organization=$1/ || organization=
```

`[ "$1" ]` tests to see if `$1` is empty or not.  If it is not empty, then `[ "$1" ]` returns true and the command after `&&` is executed.  If it is false, the command after `||` is executed.